How to Use Secret in Amplify Nuxt App Sever
I'm trying to use Amplify's Secret as per https://docs.amplify.aws/vue/deploy-and-host/fullstack-branching/secrets-and-vars/#access-secrets .
My issue is that I seem to only be able to call the query that calls the function that fetches the secret (a bit crazy but thats what the docs say) from client side, not within the server side of my app. So that kind of seems to defeat the purpose. How am I supposed to get this data to the server?
Ex code:
const client = await runAmplifyApi(event, (contextSpec) => generateClient())
try {
const { data } = await client.queries.getSecret()
console.log("data", data)
} catch (error) {
console.error("Failed to fetch:", error)
}
gives error:
ERROR  Failed to fetch: Client could not be generated. This is likely due to Amplify.configure() not being called prior to generateClient() or because the configuration passed to Amplify.configure() is missing GraphQL provider configuration
